# How do you merge(/mergeAll) a Signal of (an array of) Signals in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-signals

In rxjs-land, you can merge multiple Observables with the `merge` operator. If you have an array of Observables, you simply spread that array into the merge operator, like so: `merge(...arrayOfObservables)`. And if you have a 'higher-order' Observable (an Observable that emits Observables), you can use `mergeAll`.

I'm looking to do something similar to `mergeAll` with Angular's new Signals. I have a Signal which holds an array of Signals, `all_the_states = signal([] as Signal<any>[])`. `all_the_states` gets added to (and removed from) over time. That works easily enough via `mutate`. Now I want to create a simple Signal `latest_state` that always holds the latest value of any of the 'inner' Signals.

I thought I could simply "take a trip to rxjs-land, merge, and go back", i.e. do the following:

```
latest_state = toSignal(
    merge(...this.all_the_states().map((single) => toObservable(single))),
    { initialValue: null }
  )
```

However, when I add something to `all_the_states`, `latest_state` just stays null.

I've also tried

```
higher_order_observable: Observable<Observable<any>[]> =
  toObservable(this.selection_streams).pipe(
    map(signals => signals.map(signal => toObservable(signal)))
  )
single_observable: Observable<any> =
  this.higher_order_observable.pipe(mergeAll(), mergeAll())
latest_state = toSignal(this.single_observable, { initialValue: null })
```

which works as far as the types are concerned - though I'm not sure about the double `mergeAll` - but in that case Angular gives me the error `NG0203: toObservable() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with 'runInInjectionContext'` (before execution even gets to the double `mergeAll`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [OZ_](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680786/oz) for leading me onto the right track! Turns out my initial solution of

```
latest_state = toSignal(
    merge(...this.all_the_states().map((single) => toObservable(single))),
    { initialValue: null }
  )
```

wasn't too far off. I "just" needed to bring the reading of `all_the_states` and the `toObservable`-calls into a "reactivity" / "injection" context. Namely by wrapping with Angular's runInInjectionContext, and a local `Injector`. Plus an additional `mergeAll` was needed.

So, here's the code: In the Angular Component or - in my case - Service, get a hold of an Injector:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';

class ComponentOrService {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }
}
```

Then, within that Component/Service I do the following (split into several steps, as each step is fairly involved):

```
all_the_states_with_inner_observables =
  computed(() => runInInjectionContext(this.injector,
    () => this.all_the_states().map((single) => toObservable(single))
  ))
states_as_obs_of_obs = toObservable(computed(() =>
  merge(...this.all_the_states_with_inner_observables())
))
latest_state_as_obs = this.states_as_obs_of_obs.pipe(mergeAll())
latest_state = toSignal(this.latest_state_as_obs, { initialValue: null })
```

Comment: I've since found out that, instead of using runInInjectionContext, one can also pass the config object `{injector: this.injector}` as a second argument to `toObservable` (or any of the signal-related constructor functions)

Answer (score 1):

You have a signal that holds an array of signals - something like this?

```
const all_the_states = signal([new signal(1), new signal(2)]);
```

If that is the case, then you can simply use a computed function to map the signals to an array of their values.  No need to involve rxjs at all.

```
const latest_state = computed(() => all_the_states().map(x => x());
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rarubi?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: Hmm, thanks, but that's not quite what I'm looking for - I want to get the *single* latest state of any of the inner signals - that is, if `all_the_states` has type `: Signal<Signal<number>[]>`, `latest_state` should be `: Signal<number>`, and hold the number that was changed most recently.

Comment: I see what you're saying (I was thinking you wanted something like combineLatest).  I actually tried to create a specific signal called megeSignal in a library I created (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ddtmm/angular-signal-generators), but it didn't work out.  Basically in my unit tests emissions would get skipped in close succession.  I think something about this behavior changed in Angular 16.2, but I have yet to investigate it.  If you look at the repo for that project, you'll see a "RefSignal" in internal, that was the key to it.  Good luck.

Comment: I figured it how to make the "to rxjs and back" approach work, see [the answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77207705/4602253)

Answer (score 1):

```
latest_state = toSignal(
    merge(...this.all_the_states().map((single) => toObservable(single))),
    { initialValue: null }
  )
```

The problem with this code is that you are reading the signal outside of the reactivity context:

```
...this.all_the_states()
```

Here a Signal is being read, but outside of the reactivity context - there is no consumer to be registered, so no consumer will be notified when this Signal gets a new value.

Daniel Gimenez already gave you a very good answer on how to do what you want in the most effective way, I just wanted to explain why your code works not as you expect.

To understand better what is reactivity context, you can read this my [article](https://medium.com/@eugeniyoz/dependency-graph-in-angular-signals-53ee47f75e21).

Comment: Aha! As I've commented there, Mr. Gimenez' solution wasn't what I was looking for, but your answer+article lead me to what I needed: Bringing the reading of `all_the_states` (and the `toObservable`-calls) into a "reactivity" / "injection" context. Namely with Angular's `runInInjectionContext` and a (constructor-injected) `injector: Injector`. I will create a seperate answer to show all the code.